# AWS Cloudfront bad request: troubleshooting ideas?

Tags: amazon-web-services

S3 bucket linked to cloudfront. Have ~10 other sites working with this config. Something with one is off. Keeps giving this error. I know cloudfront doesn't know what to serve, but the domain listed in domain origin works (it points to the S3 static website endpoint. 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZShW.png)

Any thoughts on troubleshooting this? Basically S3 domain is working but xxx.Cloudfront.net domain is not working.

```
 Matts-Air:~ mattmcmahon$ curl -v d3frgd8bi2nxwe.cloudfront.net
* Rebuilt URL to: d3frgd8bi2nxwe.cloudfront.net/
*   Trying 13.33.74.78...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to d3frgd8bi2nxwe.cloudfront.net (13.33.74.78) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: d3frgd8bi2nxwe.cloudfront.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: CloudFront
< Date: Sun, 11 Mar 2018 03:07:39 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 551
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
< Via: 1.1 0b202e2428f14940b06527255fa020ea.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: z5ZO5OJiCwokDDrChXm9wf1qh0hcPaTsTkLIBftNtJh7BXtVGReoww==
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Bad request.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: z5ZO5OJiCwokDDrChXm9wf1qh0hcPaTsTkLIBftNtJh7BXtVGReoww==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
* Connection #0 to host d3frgd8bi2nxwe.cloudfront.net left intact
</BODY></HTML>Matts-Air:~ mattmcmahon$
```

traceroute is

```
Matts-Air:~ mattmcmahon$ traceroute d3frgd8bi2nxwe.cloudfront.net
traceroute: Warning: d3frgd8bi2nxwe.cloudfront.net has multiple addresses; using 52.85.89.140
traceroute to d3frgd8bi2nxwe.cloudfront.net (52.85.89.140), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  fios_quantum_gateway (192.168.1.1)  1.702 ms  2.147 ms  1.202 ms
 2  lo0-100.washdc-vfttp-310.verizon-gni.net (108.51.54.1)  6.215 ms  3.408 ms  2.802 ms
 3  b3310.washdc-lcr-21.verizon-gni.net (100.41.128.162)  4.476 ms  5.767 ms  7.745 ms
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  0.et-10-1-0.gw3.nyc41.alter.net (140.222.237.215)  12.126 ms
    0.et-9-1-0.gw3.nyc41.alter.net (140.222.228.227)  11.580 ms
    0.et-10-3-0.gw3.nyc41.alter.net (140.222.238.77)  11.370 ms
 7  amazon-gw.customer.alter.net (157.130.0.238)  11.757 ms  9.893 ms  10.794 ms
 8  52.93.1.103 (52.93.1.103)  25.801 ms
    52.93.1.107 (52.93.1.107)  21.451 ms
    52.93.1.105 (52.93.1.105)  16.229 ms
 9  52.93.1.46 (52.93.1.46)  18.857 ms
    52.93.1.60 (52.93.1.60)  17.363 ms
    52.93.1.62 (52.93.1.62)  18.661 ms
10  54.240.228.49 (54.240.228.49)  17.366 ms  16.632 ms
    54.240.202.49 (54.240.202.49)  15.007 ms
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  server-52-85-89-140.jfk6.r.cloudfront.net (52.85.89.140)  19.037 ms  17.864 ms  15.752 ms
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include your configuration as there are a lot of things that could cause that, and a needle in a haystack without it.

Comment: Can you give us the dzczcexample.cloudfront.net hostname?  Or, capture the entire response with `curl -v` and edit it into the question?  If you have a hostname pointed to this distribution in DNS but it is not configured correctly as an Alternate Domain Name in the distribution settings, and you are actually accessing CloudFront using that name, that would be one explanation for this error, but you didn't mention whether you are doing this.

Comment: Try https per https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=92583

Comment: ANSWER:  the name of the S3 bucket was too different than the URL. I've gotten away with not including www/.com in the name but this name was BBBBB and the website is aaaa.com

Changing the name of the bucket solved the problem.